# Não consigo importar minhas bibliotecas (como a PIL) de Python pelo PyDev do Eclipse, o que pode ser?

Tags: eclipse, biblioteca, pydev

Abri um código no PyDev do Eclipse e tá dando erro na linha de importação das bibliotecas! O erro é: "Unresolved import: Image" O que pode ser?

Comment: Que erro aparece? edite a pergunta e coloque ele.

Comment: Tudo certo, editado...